# How long will it take for Google's disavow tool to work?

Tags: seo, backlinks, disavow-links

I had updated the disavow list on March 18th  with spammy domains which were linked to my site. Those links still show up in Google Search Console.

I Wanna know how long does it need to take effect?

Comment: I don't think that disavowing links will prevent them from being listed in search console.   Google uses disavow to maybe lift a penalty applied against your site because of the spammy links.

Comment: I believe that Google only discounts the link when it re-crawls the page that contains the link, this can be a few days, weeks or even months... and I heard that some people even spam links to those pages to attempt to get Google to recrawl them faster... While Panda may be realtime now, I don't think the auditing of disavow is...

Answer (score 1):

I did a disavow in March 2017 after a popular pages with many spammy links lost all ranking. It took 10 days for it to reappear in Google search. I'd say it regained about 90% of it's former ranking.

All of the links I disavowed still show up in Search Console. The only way to truly remove them is to request the site webmaster to remove them and hope they oblige.